# Vertical Panel and Doc Layout Panel in GWT

Tags: gwt, panel

My Layout Structure is in the image [image]

Brief about Image: HTMLPanel is RootPanel and 2 Vertical Panels, one header and other content Panel. 2nd vertical panel has DockLayoutPanel.
Now My Problem is my DockLayout is not showing when i run the Project
code for Home Page

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
     <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="contentPane" ></g:VerticalPanel>
     <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="headerPane" styleName="{style.upper-titlebar-container}" ></g:VerticalPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

code for Content Panel

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
             <g:north size='4'>
                <g:Label> Hello </g:Label>
             </g:north>
             <g:east size="7.0">
                  <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="EdgeBandingPane"></g:HTMLPanel>
             </g:east>
             <g:west size="5.8" >
                  <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="PartsPane"></g:HTMLPanel>
             </g:west>

             <g:center >
                  <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="PanelsPane"></g:HTMLPanel>
             </g:center>
             <g:south size="5">
               <g:Label> Hello </g:Label>
             </g:south>
        </g:DockLayoutPanel>

    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

The Widgets which Iam adding are displaying in the output but my Dock Panel is not showing.
I am not getting the the problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

GWT *LayoutPanels do not automatically work when nested in *Panels (the ones without Layout). Thats because of different approaches of layouting:

- Layout Panels use absolute CSS layouting where the size must be given by the parent element
- "Normal" Panels grow with their content

To nest LayoutPanels in Panels, you have to set fixed sizes and call onResize whenever the size cahnges.
But alternatively, you can try to only work with LayoutPanels. If I'm right you want to have a header with a dynamic height (the height is defined by it's content).
In that case you should Use HeaderPanel. For the Header you can use a VerticalPanel. As container for your (exchangable) content you can use a SimpleLayoutPanel which is a LayoutPanel that hosts one widget:

```
<g:HeaderPanel>
    <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="headerPane"></g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:SimpleLayoutPanel ui:field="contentPane"></g:SimpleLayoutPanel>
</g:HeaderPanel>
```

And from my point of view the extra HTMLPanel around the DockLayoutPanel of the content should be removed to ensure that the size is correctly set from the outside:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
     <g:north size='4'>
        <g:Label> Hello </g:Label>
     </g:north>
     <g:east size="7.0">
          <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="EdgeBandingPane"></g:HTMLPanel>
     </g:east>
     <g:west size="5.8" >
          <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="PartsPane"></g:HTMLPanel>
     </g:west>
     <g:center >
          <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="PanelsPane"></g:HTMLPanel>
     </g:center>
     <g:south size="5">
       <g:Label> Hello </g:Label>
     </g:south>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Edit: HTMLPanel should only be necessary for "manual" layouting. Do not use it to only wrap one other widget/panel.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I have cleared the HTMLPanel around the DockLayoutPanel, I can see the Layout in my designer tab but not in the output. only my header(Vertical Layout) is showing, not getting where I am missing.

Comment: There was a problem in the code I posted above (I fixed it): The "headerPane" must be the first child of the HeaderPanel and the contentPane must be the second one. I hope that fixes the problem.

Comment: The problem is not with the order, It may be because of my presenter. When debugging the project "HeaderPane" ParentPresenter is "HomePresenter" but  "contentPane" ParentPresenter is NULL. I have missed somewhere in adding it in my presenter. Do you have an idea where I am missing. I have used GWTP.

Comment: I don't know GWTP very much as we always use the Activity/Place framework included in current versions of GWT.

Comment: With the rule 'Do not nest **LayoutPanels in anything other than a **LayoutPanel unless you set a fixed size for it', how can a SimpleLayoutPanel be nested in the HeaderPanel?  Is the rule more specific in that anything that implements `RequiresResize` must be nested in a widget that implements `ProvidesResize`?  Looking at `HeaderPanel` and `SimpleLayoutPanel`, that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: There are few exceptions for this rule. HeaderPanel is one of them. HeaderPanel is some kind of hybrid Widget (not a real *LayoutPanel). It expects the header and footer content to have a "natural" size based on it's content. Dependent on the size of the header and footer, the content is set a fixed size. So for the content widget it behaves like a *LayoutPanel.